# ROS and text messaging

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am not sure if this is a right forum to ask this question.

I want to send a message to any mobile phone using ROS. The application is to notify robot position through text message. Is there any package which can communicate through GSM/ GPRS modem and send text to Mobile devices.

Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10394/ros-and-text-messaging/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I think you have a few options.  If you have an Android phone, then you could connect it up and write a node using RosJava and then use the android.telephony SmsManager to send out your texts:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html
This has the advantage of not needing any equipment other than what you carry.  But you can't use your phone while on the robot.  :)

Another great option would be something like this:
http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9311.  This board is great because it just appears as a /dev/ttyUSB* serial device since it uses an FTDI chip (commonly used everywhere, including ROS).  The key with this is to make sure the frequencies supported include those of at least one of your GSM providers (in the US: T-Mobile and AT&T).

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google Voice has a nice set of Python bindings to send SMS messages. The project is called [pygooglevoice](http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/). All you need is a free Google Voice account.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2